# When we create a JPA project in RAD 8 what is generic 2.0 and rad jpa platform?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, rad

I am trying to create a jpa 2.0 project in RAD 8 and i am using websphere 8, i would like to know what is the difference between the Pratforms Generic 2.0 and rad jpa 2.0 platform. I get these two options in the drop down, also please let me know how to get hibernate provider in this dropdown?